# Deploy Django project on google Cloud App Engine with external libraries

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Good day!

I need to deploy an app on Python Django with following libs:

- certifi==2017.4.17
- chardet==3.0.4
- Django==1.11.2
- httplib2==0.10.3
- idna==2.5
- oauth2==1.9.0.post1
- psycopg2==2.7.1
- pytz==2017.2
- requests==2.18.1
- urllib3==1.21.1

And I have to connect it to PostgreSQL database.

So, **what environment shall I use**? Standard or Flexible?

And **how shall I install those libraries** to the environment?

P.S.

I've tried everything: `app.yaml`, `appengine_config.py`, I has installed libs directly to source ('libs' folder), and adding libs to `app.yaml`, and even `google.appengine.ext.ndb.django_middleware.NdbDjangoMiddleware`

In the end I have:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dynamic module
>   does not define init function (init_psycopg)

Answer (score 1):

> So, **what environment shall I use**? Standard or Flexible?

Your starting point should be the [Choosing an App Engine Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) guide, taking into consideration all your requirements.

> And I have to connect it to PostgreSQL database.

This requirement makes the choice pretty easy. From [Connecting from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine):

> This page provides language-specific links to informaton about how to
>   set up a connection from an App Engine flexible environment
>   application to a Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL instance.
>
> ```
> Note: Connection from an App Engine standard environment application
> to a PostgreSQL instance is not supported.
> ```

So flexible environment it is.

> And **how shall I install those libraries** to the environment?

This dependends on the environment you use. What you tried was the standard env way.

In the flexible environment dependencies are handled differently. From [Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#dependencies):

> The runtime looks for a [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file in your
>   application's source directory and uses [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) to install any
>   dependencies before starting your application. For more information on
>   declaring and managing packages, see [Using Python Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries)