# Google App Engine (GAE) Improperly Configured Database

Tags: django, google-app-engine, pycharm

I have a working Django project that will deploy using Heroku. I am having trouble getting the app to deploy on GAE. When I run it locally, I get an error referring to an Improperly Configured database backend.

Any help would be appreciated.

> Error:
>
> ```
> ...
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
> ImproperlyConfigured: 'postgresql' isn't an available database backend. 
> Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
>     'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3' <br>
>
>  Error was: No module named postgresql.base
> ...
> ```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "latest"

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <cloudsql-connection-string>
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

If I change the Engine to

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions

pip freeze returns:

> Django==1.11.4 psycopg2==2.7.3.1 pytz==2017.2

Comment: Your import error suggests you don't have that library installed into your application (it may be installed into your local system, but that doesn't help).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I still don't understand what needs to be done. Perhaps you can expand it a little. It is my understanding that the `pip install psycopg2` should install all dependencies on a Windows system (which this is). I have also created an identical application configured to work outside of GAE, and it works fine. Also, wouldn't the `pip freeze` output suggest that it is installed for this application?

Comment: A GAE app is not a regular python app, your expectations are incorrect. A GAE (standard environment) app can either request a library provided by the GAE sandbox or one included in the app itself. Whatever is installed on your local system is irellevant. See [Using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)

Comment: Donno if relevant for your case (I'm not a django user, can't tell if you really want to connect to a PostgreSQL instance) but if you do you might want to check this post as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190591/deploy-django-project-on-google-cloud-app-engine-with-external-libraries/45191889#45191889

Comment: Dan, these are really helpful comments! Thank you for the assist so far. It turned out that I am deploying an app in the standard environment, but I wanted to make one in the flex environment. It seems that the decision in the environment is made in the app.yaml file. So, (if I understand correctly) when I used the app.yaml above I told GAE to use a standard env (which does not allow psycopg2). My next step is to create a requirements.txt file and rewrite the app.yaml for the flex env. Additionally, PyCharm seems to setup the GAE project assuming a STD env based on their app.yaml.

Comment: Can't confirm, I'm using the older PyCharm (5.0.6), not sure what's in the latest version. I *think* you should still be able to use PyCharm with flex environment for most of the work, with the exception of deploying to GAE (which doesn't work for std env either if there are multiple modules). Just don't mark the project as a GAE one as that brings in the standard env sandbox into the picture. Code in PyCharm, but deploy and manage the GAE app itself through direct SDK cmds. I also switch between the GAE SDK (which I prefer) and the cloud SDK (which starts to get ahead) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The GAE standard env. does not allow for psycopg2, and it seems that my original app.yaml (above) instructed GAE to allocate a standard env. instance. This disconnect was highlighted by Dan's comments (above). The correct procedure here is to 1) change the app to be able to deploy on GAE standard, or 2) change the app.yaml to deploy on a GAE flex (according to my current understanding). 
The following pages seem to help on the second option (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading) and (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app).